# Using sub workflow inside main workflow

Tags: c#, xaml, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a problem loading workflow XAML in a dynamic way when I am using another workflow inside.

My main Workflow - MainWorkflow.xaml. having inside another workflow - SubWorkflow.xaml
In run time When I load the Main.xaml am getting the following error:

```
{"CacheMetadata for activity 'FlowManager.Flows.MainWorkflow' through 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException: Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:FlowManager.Flows}SubWorkflow'
```

The code for loading the workflow:

```
public object Load(Dictionary<string, object> inputs)
{
    object returnValue = null;

    ActivityXamlServicesSettings settings = new ActivityXamlServicesSettings
    {
        //since the workflow contains expression, the following flag must be set to true
        CompileExpressions = true
    };


    WorkflowApplication wfApp =
        new WorkflowApplication(
            ActivityXamlServices.Load(Path, settings), inputs)
        {
            Completed = delegate (WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                returnValue = e.Outputs["returnValue"];
                syncEvent.Set();
            },
            Idle = delegate (WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e) { idleEvent.Set(); }                    
    };

    wfApp.Run();
    syncEvent.WaitOne();
    return returnValue;
}
```

changing the loading of the workflow by creating an instance of Main and not by loading the XAML, works perfectly

```
        WorkflowApplication wfApp =
            new WorkflowApplication(new MainWorkflow(), inputs)
```

Any Ideas how I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, needed to add an assembly reference with a XamlXmlReaderSettings object

```
    var xamlReaderSettings = new XamlXmlReaderSettings()
    {
        LocalAssembly = typeof(GetVmIp).Assembly
    };
    var reader = new XamlXmlReader(Path, xamlReaderSettings);


    WorkflowApplication wfApp =
        new WorkflowApplication(
            ActivityXamlServices.Load(reader, settings), inputs)
```

and it works.